# java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset while Reading Mails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection reset;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I have a service to read mails from outlook. Receiving the above error randomly. What would be the root cause of this issue.
Using JAVA 8 and javax.mail-1.6.2 to read mails.

Below is my mail settings

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: How often does the error occur?

Comment: there could be a (conection) leak in your code (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18954423/592355)) ..or if you operate your jakarta "within a cloud" [read here](https://medium.com/swlh/fix-a-random-network-connection-reset-issue-in-docker-kubernetes-5c57a11de170) (kubernetes)

Comment: @MarkTobin this error occurs randomly once or twice in a day

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more likely to be a network issue than an issue with your application. It might be worth having a look [here](http://net-informations.com/java/err/reset.htm) to see if any of those probable causes are likely or possible in your circumstance.
Having had a similar issue with outlook previously with no root cause established, mitigation is also an option. Below shows a basic retry mechanism which, in practical terms, eliminated the issue.

```
            // send email with try-catch loop 
            int count = 0;
            int maxTries = 5;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    // get and set your protocols
                    mailSender.send(message);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (++count == maxTries) {
                        // Give up and throw the error
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
```