# Socket connection reset only in Eclipse, but not in Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, terminal

I am working on my school assignment, making Tic-Tac-Toe game. My teacher is running a server and we interact by sending objects back and forth.
Since it's a school project, I can't post my whole code, but here is the particular part I am getting the error. If I run this in terminal, it works perfectly fine (I am getting the object from the server).

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
System.out.println(in.readObject()); // i get the name of the object
```

However, if I run exactly the same problem using Eclipse.
I get the error: System.out.println(in.readObject()) is on line 29.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2303)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2596)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at here.TicTacToeClient.main(TicTacToeClient.java:29)
```

Any reason why it runs in terminal but not in Eclipse??

Answer (score 0):

Your reading the object twice as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947088/socketexception-connection-reset-on-server-with-objectinputstream)

Eclipse is closing it's connection after you receive the obeject the first time and then when you to try to print it out it is throwing the exception due to a closed socket.